# Parsing file returns error "thread 'main' panicked"

Tags: xml, rust, serde

I'm struggling with serde-xml-rs and hope someone can help me out. I've been able to parse a single "pet" from the sample XML below. But, when I try to parse a file with two "pet" entries under "pets", as illustrated below, I get the error "thread 'main' panicked at 'called `Result::unwrap()` on an `Err` value: Error(Custom("missing field `species`"), State { next_error: None, backtrace: Some(stack backtrace:..."

Fairly new to both Rust and wrestling with XML, so I hope it's a simple error or misunderstanding somewhere.  Pointers most appreciated.

```rust
extern crate serde;
extern crate serde_xml_rs;
#[macro_use]
extern crate serde_derive;

use serde_xml_rs::{from_str, to_string};

#[derive(Debug, Serialize, Deserialize, PartialEq)]
struct Pets {
    #[serde(rename = "pet")]
    pets: Vec<Pet>,
}

#[derive(Debug, Serialize, Deserialize, PartialEq)]
struct Pet {
    species: String,
    name: String,
}

fn main() {
    let src = r##"<?xml version="1.0"?>
        <pets>
        <pet>
        <species>cat</species>
        <name>Leroy</name>
        </pet>
        <pet>
        <species>dog</species>
        <name>Rowdy</name>
        </pet>
        </pets>
        "##;

    let pet: Pet = from_str(&src).unwrap();
    //println!("{:#?}",pet);
}
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with serde's xml requirements, but I'm pretty darn sure you can't parse a `<pets />` with multiple `<pet />` nodes as a single `Pet`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a very simple error indeed. You just need to use `Pets` type instead of `Pet`:

```rust
fn main() {
    ...

    let pets: Pets = from_str(&src).unwrap();
    println!("{:#?}", pets);
}
```

Comment: @ghoetker don't be discouraged, you got almost everything right. `rust` is a strong typed language, minding the types will get you a long way.